# Add new columns with values to dataframe after filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

This is something I find myself doing surprisingly often, so I was wondering whether there was a faster / "R" way to do it:

```
A:
      a     b
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1 FALSE
2     2  TRUE
3     3  TRUE
4     4 FALSE

B:
      c     d eeyyccc
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1    11    AA      55
2    22    BB      66
```

What I want to get is the following: Merge B to the subset `A[A$b==T,]`, filling all unknown values with NA.

```
      a     b     c     d eeyyccc
  <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     1 FALSE    NA   NA      NA
2     2  TRUE    11   AA      55
3     3  TRUE    22   BB      66
4     4 FALSE    NA   NA      NA
```

Is there a quick "R" way to do this by filtering and creating the columns "on the fly"? I can't use any of the column names of B explicitely since I don't know what they are beforehand...

```
A <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3,4), b=c(F,T,T,F))
B <- tibble(c=c(11,22), d=c("AA", "BB"), eeyyccc=c(55,66))
```

Is there something (in dplyr or base R) that allows me to do this in one line, e.g. like:

```
A[A$b==T,] <- cbind(A$b==T,B) # does not work
```

Comment: One option is `replace` i.e. `A %>% mutate(c = replace(NA, b, B$c))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `replace` either with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
   mutate(c = replace(NA, b, B$c))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  a b         c
#  <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
#1  1.00 F      NA  
#2  2.00 T      11.0
#3  3.00 T      22.0
#4  4.00 F      NA
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
transform(A, c = replace(NA, b, B$c))
```

#### Update

With the updated data

```
library(purrr)
A[names(B)] <- map(B, ~ replace(NA, A$b, .x))
A
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#      a b         c d     eeyyccc  
#   <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1  1.00 F      NA   <NA>     NA  
#2  2.00 T      11.0 AA       55.0
#3  3.00 T      22.0 BB       66.0
#4  4.00 F      NA   <NA>     NA
```

Or with `base R`

```
A[names(B)] <- lapply(B, function(x) replace(NA, A$b, x))
```

Comment: But these imply that I only have one column c, right? - instead, i have lots of columns where I don't even know their names...

Comment: @Thomas IN that case use either `mutate_at` or `mutate_if`  with column index/column names or based on the column type

Comment: Maybe my example is not clear enough, I tried to make it very simple. Instead of just c, my B has lots of columns with names I dont know beforehand so I won't be able to hardcode them...

Comment: @Thomas it is better to provide a better example to code it correctly

Comment: @Thomas and what about the columns in 'A'.  Is it just a single logical column to do the comparisons?

Comment: I edited my example to make my problem more clear. The column in a is an example for how I filter the dataset.

Comment: Thanks. I have never worked with purrr and will have to look at the documentation to understand what exactly map() is doing, but your updated code snippet does exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option. The key is to create a merging variable (`M`) and then conduct merge. No need to specify any column names in `B`.

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
  mutate(M = ifelse(b, cumsum(b), NA)) %>%
  left_join(B %>% mutate(M = 1:n()), by = "M") %>%
  select(-M)
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#       a b         c d     eeyyccc
#   <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1  1.00 F      NA   NA       NA  
# 2  2.00 T      11.0 AA       55.0
# 3  3.00 T      22.0 BB       66.0
# 4  4.00 F      NA   NA       NA
```